# How to import all columns of a csv as Strings in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-design, google-bigquery, airflow

I am using airflow to unarchive `CSV` files (e.g. FILE__YYYYMMDD.csv) from a **GCS** bucket to **BigQuery**. Since the file evolved throughout the months, its schema changed (More columns were added). So I used the option `autodetect` to set the table schema in BQ. Unfortunately, some key columns are autodetected wrong (detects hexa hashes as floats for some reason), and so I want to import every column as a String, then cast it within the query that is supposed to analyze the tables...

1. Do you recommend this approach ?
2. How do I tell Bigquery "**autodetect the column (names), but set their types as String**"

Comment: Do you import in a new table or an existing table?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I use WRITE_TRUNCATE on the sharded tables (one per day)... why is that relevant?

Comment: If the table already exist, create the schema before and then import your files.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere As I've said, the schema changes. E.g. In the 2020/12/01 it had 7 columns, in the 2021/03/01 it had 8 columns, ... presently it has even more. The use of autodetect is important here in order to make the import of these files generic and automatable.

Comment: and at any rate, the tables do not exist. The job is to import from GCS to BQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the schema can change at any time, the safest way is to create a workflow:

- Import the new file in a temporary table
- Create a merge query to merge the data in the temporary table to the final one. In that merge query, you can cast the fields in the format that you want to merge the data in the final table.

(The temporary table will be deleted automatically)

---

**EDIT 1**

Following the comment discussion, your use case isn't achievable out of the box on BigQuery. You must do more thing before the integration.

The idea that I have is the following:

- When a file comes in, get the header line
- Get the schema of the target table

  - If the header has more fields than the target table, update the schema with the new columns with the STRING type.
- Load the file in BigQuery with the schema that you deduce from the header reading, and the `allow_jagged_rows` parameters to allow the integration with less column that the final schema. Load the file from Cloud Storage, not from your code.

Comment: Import the new file in the temporary table using what schema? + Autodetect assigns the wrong types

Comment: Yes, but you perform a merge request in the final table to cast the wrong type in correct ones.

Comment: That won't work. Let me illustrate :

A hash column (supposed to be imported as string) is somehow detected as integer, so its value changes instead of "0x..." i get "1982...", I cannot try to reconvert it as a string since I lost the information "0x...."

Comment: But your input about creating a workflow gives me an idea. I think I will manually create a schema of the "latest" and most comprehensive file (with all the columns, their names, modes and types), and put it in a dictionary, then dynamically recreate the json needed as an input for the BQ import, after I parse the header of the csv file and compare it to the dictionary in place.

Comment: Do you need all the column all the time? Or only the core column, and don't care the new ones that the time can add?

Comment: It depends on the date of input. If for example I am trying to import an older file, I'll only need a few columns (that existed at the time), if I want to import a newer file, I'll take all the columns

Comment: Of course, this method does not answer the "how do you `autodetect` columns in a file, and force the `STRING` type on all of them", I hope someone will shed light whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I updated my answer, with a possible workaround. Nothing out of the box, but something simple to write and that can do the job.